# Enabling cells in JFace Tables

Tags: java, jface

I have made a table in jFace which has columns, but when the application runs, the cells in that column is not in editable/enabled mode. How do I enable the cells in the table column?

Below is the table and table column code:

```
Table Employee = EmployeeViewer.getTable();
Employee.setHeaderVisible(true);
Employee.setLinesVisible(true);
Employee.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

TableColumn Name = new TableColumn(Employee, SWT.LEFT);
Name.setText("Name       ");
Name.pack();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `Table Column` editable by adding an `EditingSupport`. See [Section 2.1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html) of this tutorial.